# make exception in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I can remove all periods inside a string using this code:

```js
const usage = "I was sent... to protect you.".replace(/\s?\.\.\.\s?/, " ... "); 
const rawUsage = usage.toLowerCase().replace(/\,|\?|\!|\:|\./g,'');  // removes all dots
console.log(rawUsage);
```

The above code will remove all dots in the string. the issue is that I do not want to remove triple dots. actually I want to make triple dots exception.

the desired result of the above code is:

"I was sent ... to protect you"

Comment: `/\.{3}/g ` then searches for `...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const usage = "I was sent... to protect you."; 
const rawUsage = usage.toLowerCase().split(/\s?\.\.\.\s?/).map((s)=>{return s.replace(/\./g,"");}).join(" ... "); 
console.log(rawUsage);
```

Answer (score 2):

You might match and capture the three-dot pattern and restore it in the result if this group matches, else, remove the match:

```js
const usage = "I was sent... to protect you.".replace(/\s*\.{3}\s*/, " ... "); 
const rawUsage = usage.toLowerCase().replace(/(\s\.{3}\s)|[,?!:.]/g, (x,y) => y || x );
console.log(rawUsage)
```

The `/(\s\.{3}\s)|[,?!:.]/g` regex matches and captures a whitespace + 3 dots + a whitespace into Group 1, and then matches a `,`, `?`, `!`, `:` or `.`. If Group 1 matches, `y` is returned (i.e. the Group 1 value), else, `x` is returned (the whole match).

Answer (score 2):

You may use look-arounds too. Something like:

```
(?<=[\s\w])(?:\.{1,2}|\.{4,})(?=[\s\w])
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`(?<=[\s\w])`** - Represents a positive look-behind matching a whitespace or a word character before `.`.
- **`(?:\.{1,2}|\.{4,})`** - Represents a non-capturing group matching `.` dot 1, 2 times or 4 or more times but not three.
- **`(?=[\s\w])`** - Represents a positive look-ahead asserting a whitespace or a word character after the `.`.

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/k2twqg/3)

```js
const regex = /(?<=[\s\w])(?:\.{1,2}|\.{4,})(?=[\s\w])/gm;
const str = `I was sent... to protect you.
I was sent.. to protect you.
I was sent.... to protect you.
I was sent ... to protect you.
`;
const subst = ``;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your case could be solved in a simple way regardless of regex. Below is a worked solution

```js
const usage = 'I was sent... to protect you.'
const res = usage
  .replace('...', ' ... ')
  .split(' ')
  .filter(word => !!word) // reject empty word ('')
  .join(' ')

console.log(res)
```